# firebase.auth.signInWithCustomToken is not a function node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble to sign in with `signInWithCustomToken` of Firebase. I'm
getting an error like below:

```
Error creating custom token: TypeError: firebase.auth.signInWithCustomToken is not a function
```

Can any one demonstrate how to sign in with custom token in Firebase NodeJS?

Comment: Please share the [minim code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the brackets after auth? It should be:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(myToken)
```